# Python - SyntaxError: invalid syntax in a while loop

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am very new to python and I don't understand what I did wrong.
Can anyone tell me why is this syntax error popping up?

(I am using python 3)

```
while True:
print("Welcome to a Degrees Celsius to Kelvin converter.")
ready = str(input("Do you want to start converting from Degrees Celsius to Kelvin? Y/N"))

while ready.upper() = "Y":

    magicnumber = 273.15
    choice = input("If you want to convert from Celsius to Kelvin type 'celsius' ,if you want to convert from Kelvin to Celsius type 'kelvin'")

    if choice == "celsius":
        celsius = input("Type the temperature in Degrees Celsius.")
        result = int(celsius) + magicnumber
        print("%s Degrees Celsius is %s Kelvin" %(celsius, result))
    elif choice == "kelvin":
        kelvin = input("Type the temperature in Kelvin")
        result = int(kelvin) - magicnumber
        print("%s Kelvin is %s Degrees Celsius" %(kelvin, result))
```

Comment: You need `==` to compare values, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: Thank you! It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator, `==` is an equality operator. I think you meant to use

```
while ready.upper() == "Y":
```